# JSON filter method giving syntax error on IE but works fine on other browsers

Tags: jquery, json

Hi I've a nested `JSON` and I want to filter the data for empty qty values

Here is the original JSON -

```
var unfilteredJSON = {  
   "payload":{  
      "oldKeys":[  
         "125262"
      ],
      "keyData":[  
         {  
            "key":"123456",
            "products":[  
               {  
                  "prodId":"H1",
                  "qty":"1"
               },
               {  
                  "prodId":"H2",
                  "qty":""
               }
            ],
            "rushFee":"true"
         },
         {  
            "key":"234234",
            "products":[  
               {  
                  "prodId":"H1",
                  "qty":"1"
               },
               {  
                  "prodId":"H2",
                  "qty":""
               }
            ],
            "rushFee":"false"
         }
      ],
      "submit":"false"
   }
}
```

The qty key can have empty values in the object. I want to filter the data with jQuery method and remove the object with blank qty so the JSON can look like this -

```
 {  
  "payload":{  
     "oldKeys":[  
        "125262"
     ],
     "keyData":[  
        {  
           "key":"123456",
           "products":[  
              {  
                 "prodId":"H1",
                 "qty":"1"
              },
           ],
           "rushFee":"true"
        },
        {  
           "key":"234234",
           "products":[  
              {  
                 "prodId":"H1",
                 "qty":"1"
              },
           ],
           "rushFee":"false"
        }
     ],
     "submit":"false"
  }
 }
```

So, I have used the filter method the gives me the above result, which is working fine-

```
   var unfilteredJSON = {"payload":{"oldKeys":["125262"],"keyData": 
  [{"key":"123456","products":[{"prodId":"H1","qty":"1"}, 
  {"prodId":"H2","qty":""}],"rushFee":"true"},{"key":"234234","products": 
  [{"prodId":"H1","qty":"1"}, 
  {"prodId":"H2","qty":""}],"rushFee":"false"}],"submit":"false"}};
   unfilteredJSON.payload.keyData.forEach(e => 
     e.products = e.products.filter(p => p.qty)
  );
   console.log(unfilteredJSON);
```

But it's giving me the Syntax Error in Internet Explorer due to this line -

```
 unfilteredJSON.payload.keyData.forEach(e => 
     e.products = e.products.filter(p => p.qty)
  );
```

I need a work around or a different method to make this work in all browsers. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE-10 doesn't support this method.You should use jQuery.grep() instead of filter() method.

```
e.products = jQuery.grep(e,(p => p.qty))
```

Comment: Hi It's not working it still gives me an error. IE dosen't support `=>`. Can you please suggest some other method. I am currently using IE11

Comment: yes! It's the syntax error. I think there is no problem with filter method but with `=>`. Can you please suggest another method.

Comment: It would be helpful, kindly follow this link and re-arrange your code with jQuery.grep()

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Comment: ok sure you should write your anonymous function(callback) in simple way e.g.  function(){}

Comment: change format of your callback. you are using lambda expression, you should use simple format. Try

Comment: I think the answer is not printed. Can you please post again?

Comment: Can you please post the solution?